# Can't get foreign key using JAVA DatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, foreign-keys, database-metadata

i want get foreign key using java DatabaseMetaData and tried.
but i got just foreign key referring pk column and couldn't get referring unique column.
i tried using getCrossReference(), getImportedKeys() pattern and same result.

here is my code and DB is Oracle11g.

```
    ResultSet rset = databaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(null, dbName, tableName);

    while(rset.next()){
      String column_name = rset.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");
      String pk_table = rset.getString("PKTABLE_NAME");
      String pk_column = rset.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
      String constraint_name = rset.getString("FK_NAME");

      System.out.println(column_name + " ==> " + pk_column + "(TBL:" + pk_table + ")(CN:" + constraint_name + ")");
    }
    rset.close();
```

the table has two foreign keys (one is referring pk column, another is referring unique column) but i got just one log.
is there any mistakes ?
thanks.

Comment: did you tried with `getImportedKeys(null,null,tableName)`?

Comment: @bellabax : thank you bellabax. i tried and got same result.

Comment: now, i think whether it is just for foreign key for PK but i can't find description about that. :<

Answer (score 0):

to get referring unique column you have to use PKCOLUMN_NAME in the getString

```
 rset.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
```

here are the complite code :

```
ResultSet rset = databaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(null, dbName, tableName);

while(rset.next()){
    String column_name = rset.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME");
    String pk_table = rset.getString("PKTABLE_NAME");
    String pk_column = rset.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
    String constraint_name = rset.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");      
    System.out.println("  "+column_name+" reference to "+ pk_table+"("+constraint_name+")");             
}
rset.close();
```